# Passing arguments from .launch file to .yaml file

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am having problems with passing an argument into a .yaml file.

The problem is this:

```
map_type: costmap
observation_sources: scan
scan: {sensor_frame: $(arg namespace)/base_scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: $(arg namespace)/scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

I am passing the argument, "BotN" for N robots in the launch file, e.g:

```
  <include file="$(find deploy)/launch/make_robot.launch" >
    <arg name="model"          value="burger"/>
    <arg name="namespace"      value="Bot1" />
    <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="-2.5"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="4.0"/>
  </include>
```

But I get an insanely long error that doesn't really outline the issue.

Writing this in the .yaml file works, but I need it to work for multiple robots

```
scan: {sensor_frame: Bot1/base_scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: Bot1/scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

Any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391564/passing-arguments-from-.launch-file-to-.yaml-file/) by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2021-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-11-25**:
I think most people just create a separate yaml file for each robot. It's the quickest way, and the easiest to debug when things to wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think you can use `$(arg namespace)` in .yaml.
You can try using `remap` and `tf_remap`.

I'm not familiar with `tf_remap`, so I apologize if I'm wrong about it.

It should be used in `make_robot.launch` as follows.

```
<node pkg="tf" type="tf_remap" name="tf_remapper">
  <rosparam param="mappings">
    [{old: /base_scan, new: /$(arg namespace)/base_scan}]
  </rosparam
</node>

<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base">
  <remap from="/scan" to="/$(arg namespace)/scan" />
  ...
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1